# Print to debug output in VS2010 when Unicode mode is on

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, visual-studio-debugging

Easy "unicode mode" compatible way to print text string like "TEST" to debug output in Visual Studio 2010?

I've seen some instructions pointing out that I need to change some settings to do this. But I need to stick with unicode for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No biggie: `OutputDebugStringW` does the conversion for you. So you can just print `L"TEST"`, and it will convert it to `"TEST"` for you.

Comment: Actually I think that there's no conversion involved.

Comment: ["OutputDebugStringW converts the specified string based on the current system locale information and passes it to OutputDebugStringA to be displayed."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

Comment: I thought that, as anything else, this stuff was handled internally in Unicode. Uh, well, then +1. :)

Comment: You're not the first one to notice: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxtoolsdev/thread/99cb2c85-3d4a-4c30-be43-2d54c3e7aa7e